# How to create and call action button for User entity

Tags: liferay, hook, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-aui

I have created a portlet and which has the user form and on click of save buton in the class I am calling UserLocalServiceUtil.addUser() to save the user info in DB. With the following code I am printing list of users in my `view.jsp`.

```
<liferay-ui:search-container delta="10" emptyResultsMessage="no-users-were-found">
        <liferay-ui:search-container-results
                results="<%=UserLocalServiceUtil.getUsers(searchContainer.getStart(), searchContainer.getEnd())%>"
       total="<%=UserLocalServiceUtil.getUsersCount()%>" />
        <liferay-ui:search-container-row
                className="com.liferay.portal.model.User"
                keyProperty="userId"
                modelVar="user"
        >
                <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
                        name="name"
                        value="<%= user.getFullName() %>"
                />
                <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
                        name="first-name"
                        property="firstName"
                />
                <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
                        name="last-name"
                        property="lastName"
                />
                <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
                        name="screen-name"
                        property="screenName"
                />
        </liferay-ui:search-container-row>
        <liferay-ui:search-iterator />
</liferay-ui:search-container>
<liferay-ui:search-container delta="10" emptyResultsMessage="no-users-were-found" />
```

Now the screen shot for my code is as follows,

[image]

Now I wanted to enable the action controls for the users list. Is there any way to call the API methods to call and enable the follwoing actions buttons with functionality.

[image]

If that is not possible with API methods, How can add action buttons for users list so that I can edit user info.

Any suggestions that In which way I can achieve my task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are searching for is implemented in the following file: https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/users_admin/user_action.jsp

That file is included inside the last column of the search iterator.

Comment: I am doing this in a separate portlet. so you want me to add the suggsted file in my portlet and include that inside the last column of the search iterator?

Comment: Sadly cross-context shouldn't be allowed, so you have to replicate it... then you should be sure to call the right "core" actions... but it is very likely that after the action they will return to standard pages. I'm not sure because I never did so. An alternative is to replicate a great part of LR core in your portlet, but I very dislike this solution... Another approach can be to directly modify (by ext) user portlet... The problem, as I already said, is that the system isn't conceived to work in this way in the same group, but only in the same portal instance... :(